# Why the path "//" is working?

Tags: filesystems

Tested on a debian and debian-based:

```
$ cd // && pwd && ls
//
bin   build  dev  home ...
```

Why is the path `//` a valid path?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to the [POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11):

```
A pathname that begins with two successive slashes may be interpreted in an
implementation-defined manner, although more than two leading slashes shall be
treated as a single slash.
```

I'm guessing bash resolves the two slashes to a single slash, so they both mean the same thing. And according to the specification, `cd ///` should also give the same output.

You can check the inode number of the current directory using

`stat -c "%i" .`

and you'll notice that the inode number of `/` and `//` are the same.

Comment: I doubt bash does this. I rather think it is the kernel's job...

Comment: The specific of // not necessarily = / is reserved for Windows POSIX environment for which // begins a UNC name. Cygwin also behaves this way.

Comment: @joshudson Don't also forget that URI `/a/b/c` is a relative URI, while an URI `//a/b/c` is an absolute one, and `a` is the host name.

Answer (score 5):

This question has already been answered [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1910/how-linux-handles-multiple-path-separators-home-username-file).

On most [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_266) systems, multiple slashes are simply ignored.

Comment: We really do prefer that answers contain content not pointers to content. Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.